# Restricting VCR to specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vcr

Is there a way to make VCR active only when called via rspec in a Rails app?  It works great for my tests, but I don't want it to intercept requests when outside of those tests.

I get *Real HTTP connections are disabled* if I use a client to connect to the my app and the app is calling an external web service.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this work as desired with Rails.  I was able to disable VCR (WebMock, actually, which is the backend I chose for VCR) except when I'm running rspec.  For background, I initially followed the instructions [here](http://www.chrisjeon.me/blog/2013/12/15/how-to-configure-vcr-to-work-with-rails-rspec) when setting up VCR.

First, I create `config/initializers/webmock.rb`:

```
# Disable WebMock globally so it doesn't interfere with calls outside of the specs.
WebMock.disable!
```

Then I added the following around `VCR.use_cassette()` (in my case this is in `spec_helper.rb`:

```rb
config.around(:each, :vcr) do |example|
  name = example.metadata[:full_description].split(/\s+/, 2).join("/").underscore.gsub(/[^\w\/]+/, "_")
  options = example.metadata.slice(:record, :match_requests_on).except(:example_group)
+ # Only enable WebMock for the specs.  Don't interfere with calls outside of this.
+ WebMock.enable!
  VCR.use_cassette(name, options) { example.call }
+ WebMock.disable!
end
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Disabling webmock and/or VCR in non-test environments works, but a far better approach would be to only load webmock and VCR in your test environment. There's no reason to have them loaded in non-test environments.

Comment: The problem is, in my development environment I need to use a 3rd party service to code against, in this case it's a payment gateway's sandbox.  I would still like to use this environment to write tests as I develop.  It seems to be all or nothing with VCR/WebMock, by default.

Comment: VCR/WebMock being loaded (or not) in your rails development environment has nothing to do with your ability to write tests in your rails test environment that hit the payment gateway's sandbox. Your original question says "I don't want it to intercept requests when outside of those tests" -- which sounds like you don't want VCR/WebMock to be active in non-test rails environments. If that's the case, not loading them is the best way to achieve that. If that's not the case, then I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Your first interpretation of the question is correct.  I was merely trying to provide some context as to why I wanted that functionality.  I need to be able to develop tests and get the benefits of using VCR while in the 'development' rails environment.  In our workflow the 'test' rails environment is for QA and automated testing, not developing tests.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that your `VCR gem` is set in the proper group

```
# Gemfile
group :test do
  ......
  gem 'vcr'
end
```

take a look at http://natashatherobot.com/vcr-gem-rails-rspec/ for more help.